# Recreating Minutes of Meeting layout in LaTeX

Tags: sectioning, luatex, two-column

I'm trying to recreate a minutes of meeting layout in LaTeX. The goal is to match the layout of the previous minutes.

Specifically, it is the layout of the sections or each item in the minutes.
The layout is based on two columns width different widths. The first column takes about 70% of the textwidth and contains the text and decisions. The other column contains the section heading.
[image]

I've tried the minutes package but it dosen't help with this.

This is what I've got so far. From the MWE below. As you can see the section heading takes up vertical space from the text.
[image]

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=10pt,
  DIV=11,
  headings=small,
  headinclude=false,
  footinclude=true,
  headheight=36pt,
  parskip=full,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[swedish]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{§\thesection. }

\newcommand{\yrkande}[1]{
  \uline{#1 yrkar}\\
}

\newcommand{\beslut}{
  { \bfseries
  \uline{Fullmäktige beslutar\\}}
}

\newcommand{\att}[1]{
  { \bfseries
  att #1}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\punkt}[2]{
  \begin{centering}
  \@startsection
    {section}%                                 %% name
    {1}%                                       %% level
    {0pt}%                                     %% no indent from left margin
    {-1\baselineskip minus\parskip}%           %% beforeskip
    {0.4\baselineskip}%                        %% afterskip
    {\normalfont\normalsize\centering}
    { \vspace{-2em}}
  \end{centering}
  {
    \rule{\textwidth}{.6pt}
    \begin{flushright}
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
      \MakeUppercase{
      \nohyphens{
        #1
      }}
      \\ #2
    \end{minipage}
    \end{flushright}
  }
}

\makeatother

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{89}

\punkt{Mötets öppnande}{./1, ./2}
Det är är ett protokoll.


\punkt{Justering av röstlängd}{}

\yrkande{Talmannapresidiet}

Alla vi som någon gång har vart här, alla som en gång i tiden vill något
eller som bara var. Det är nu dags att resa sig upp och ta tillbaka det som
engång var vårt. Det är det enda som är värt att fightas för, det enda som
får mig att gå upp på morgonen.

\beslut
\att{ verkställa beslutet enligt bilaga }



\end{document}
```

I'm using LuaLaTeX if it matters.

Comment: i'm not familiar with the `scrartcl` class, but what you want to do is put the section heading into a box that has zero depth.  `\vss` at the end should help by avoiding warning messages, and a `\strut` at the beginning should help to keep the baseline of the first line aligned with the text first line.